# Problem with Matrix trnaspose function in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, matrix, transpose

I cannot see the problem in my matrix transpose function, it's propably very trivial.
In the first part I am creating a matrix with zeros, the size of A:

```
A = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
line = []
A_T = []
for e in A:
    linha.append(0)
for e in A[0]:
    A_T.append(linha)
```

The output seems to be identical to [[0,0,0], [0,0,0]], but the code only works if I define this 0-matrix manually, otherwise the output is [[2, 4, 6],[2, 4, 6]].

the second part of the code:

```
for e in range(len(A_T)):
    for i in range(len(A_T[0])):
        A_T[e][i] = A[i][e]
```

any ideas?

Comment: I don't know if this is an assignment, but classical python method: `A_T = list(map(list, zip(*A)))`

Comment: The issue with your current code is that you use the same list object everywhere

Comment: thank´s so much!, I would have never come to this conclusion on my own :)